# Is there a narrower wallplate for light switches?

Tags: electrical

Here is the 1000 words picture
I am replacing the metal one
[image]

Comment: Most stores should have a good selection of styles.  Size I think is covered by code/standards, so difference might not be that great, maybe trimming of the white plastic part by a bit.  The idea is to cover the box/switch plus some of the wall.  Imagine you don't mean to change to a single instead of a double.

Comment: this is a downgrade made for aesthetical reasons I would hate to have to chop the plastic one that much (I would practically need to cut that up to the corners of the metal one and that is a lot

Comment: consider painting or powder coating the metal one ... 3D printing a new one may also be an option

Comment: @jsotola  3D printing one is possible, but I think it would be against code for not being UL listed.  The plastic has to go through burning tests.  But I won't tell if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the metal cover is standard size. Measure it. Standard duplex covers are 4.875 x 4,875 inches The plastic is oversize. Take the metal cover to your local big box store and match it to a standard size cover.
In my area (Florida) standard covers can be difficult to find.

Comment: Yes you were correct. I went to a Dollar Store here in Canada and I grabbed a regular no name plate and that fit perfectly. The Home depot ones were wider

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is at least one website that sells custom-made narrow face plates, as well as some "generic" ones. https://www.kyleswitchplates.com/narrow-switch-plates/ A little bit of search-engine-foo should find you others. With the advent of 3-d printing, this seems like a straightforward business to get into. (So: caution!)

IIRC, you can get "half narrow" or "full narrow" plates, so if you are cramped for space on only one side (like a door jamb) the half-narrow works, but if you are trying to install a switch on a skinny column the full-narrow is probably what you want.

Also, they sell various permutations of n-gang, decora-vs-standard, etc.

Note that this is mostly custom stuff, so it's likely to be expensive. Meaning: don't plan for your entire house to be skinny plates, just put in ones that are really needed, unless you're the person that just won the billion dollar lottery.